# Categories, Subcategories and products in Django

Tags: python, django, model, categories

so, I have the following problem:

I am trying to create a web app with `products`, `subcategories` and `categories`.
All of them should be connected, meaning: a product can be connected or associated to a category, subcategory; a subcategory can be connected to one or many categories and so on.
All of them can be administrated by admin in the Django admin page.
Here's my models.py (all names are in spanish, but they are pretty self explanatory )

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Subcategoria(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    producto = models.ManyToManyField(Producto) # unique=True,

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Categoria(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    producto = models.ManyToManyField(Producto)
    subcategoria = models.ManyToManyField(Subcategoria)#, blank=True, default=None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

This code runs pretty good, except that it automatically adds all existing products to subcategories, categories, all subcategories to categories and so on.
I am not able to edit or delete, which confuses me.
Any idea?

Thank you very much !

Comment: i think your problem when you create `Products`, `Subcategoria `. Can you show this code?

Comment: I would suggest writing a `__repr__` method for each class. Or do what I always do, which is have the `dataclass` decorator create the method for me.

Comment: @NgocPham you mean create as in create the model ? the piece of code is right there, I've got nothing else.

Comment: @AMC can you show me a bit of a sample code on how do you do it ? thank you !

Comment: I doubt if the structure is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship between two models defines that zero, one or more objects of the first model may be related to zero, one or more objects of the second model.  Therefore, i suggest you to use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) (Many-to-One)

So, the code becomes:

```
from django.db import models

class Categoria(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre 

class Subcategoria(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria,  on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subcategoria = models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria,unique=True,on_delete= models.CASCADE) 
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria,blank=True,default=None, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Note:
ForeignKey with unique = True is somewhat similar to OneToOneField